# Clean URL with htaccess. no query string variable received

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on urls of a site. I want to convert the following url into

http://dev.steelogic.com/solution.php?id=metalbuildingproduct

this url

http://dev.steelogic.com/solution/metalbuildingproduct

this is the htaccess code I am using.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$    $1.php?id=$2
```

I don't know anything about htaccess. usually I just copy paste the text and it works.
the url with ?id= works fine
but when try to use the 2nd url it doesn't have any id.
I have to do this to many other pages as well and the all contain [.php?id=] which I want to replace with [/] slash

Comment: How I read it, you say that `solution.php` is loaded, but `$_GET['id']` is `NULL`? That's impossible with this rule alone however...

Comment: yes. there is not $_GET at all. what should I do then to get the url working

Comment: What other rules do you have? Both in any `.htaccess` and in your main config file...

Comment: nothing. I need only one rule thats enforcing the www with url

Comment: What happens if you remove the rule you have in your question and go to `/solution/metalbuildingproduct`? Does it still load `solution.php`?

Comment: yes I just checked. if I remove the .htaccess file at all the page still loads with the same error

Comment: yes every file can be run without any extesnion if its present there and has no name conflict a directory. I will be grateful if you can solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule in your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I tried this but didn't get the result I need. still the $_GET['id'] is null

Comment: Where does the $1 in the last RewriteCond come from? Otherwise, the RewriteRule looks OK to me.

Comment: `$1` and `$2` come from `RewriteRule` actually. Also try updated code and make sure it is in `DocumentRoot`.

Comment: I just added `Options -MultiViews` line to fix this.

Comment: yes @anubhava I tried it you can visit the link and see the error yourself if you want.

Comment: So `solution.php`, `.htaccess` are all placed in `DocumentRoot`? And are you sure you have `-MultiViews` line?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^solution/([^/.]+)/?$ solution.php?id=$1 [PT,L,NC,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: please show us the complete code for solution.php and .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Because you say that even without this rule, going to `http://example.com/solution/asdf` loads `/solution.php` on your server, something else must be working on your url. Because you say you didn't define such a rule, it must be coming from somewhere else. Either a rule is defined somewhere else (main config file) or MultiViews is enabled. If you can't apply anubhava's solution (disabling MultiViews), move your file somewhere else, for example under `/public/solution.php`, so that url never partly matches an existing file, then use the following rule.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1.php -f #partly copied from anubhava's answer
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /public/$1.php?id=$2 [L]
```

Comment: I did it in PHP for now. I will explain later when I will be able to answer my question

Answer (score 0):

from all of the discussion I concluded that its difficult enough to do it with .htaccess as there might b some sort of module working on the urls of site from the hosting and I get both `solution` and `solution.php` directed to same page
so I did it in php for now.
as both of the following pages
http://dev.steelogic.com/solution.php?id=metalbuildingproduct

and 
http://dev.steelogic.com/solution/metalbuildingproduct

being going to same pages but with the second url I was not getting query string var. so I wrote a PHP code as I knew on each page how many vars I need so it worked for me. although it may not be a good approach but it works

```
$URI = explode("/", trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
$numElems = count($URI);
if ($numElems <= 4) {
     $arr = array();
     $arr['id'] = $URI[2];
     if (!empty($URI[3]))
       $arr['id2'] = $URI[3];
}
```

if any body can help me with .htaccess I will appreciate.